# "Tick" issue while using cookies to maintain a persistent countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, timer, countdown

The following question requires a look into the following external resources:

- [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)
- [JavaScript Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

No, this isn't one of the other "Cookie Timer not working" questions here on SO. ;)

I have crafted a persistent countdown timer that uses cookies to save a particular user's countdown state regardless of browser reloads or reboots. Everything is working great, except for when I use jQuery Countdown's "ticks" to create callbacks…

Actually, the callbacks do work if I let the timer run without reloading the page. But as soon as the page reloads, one of the callbacks doesn't work — and one of them does.

The callback that works regardless is the one that checks for the end of the timer. The one that doesn't work (after reload) is the one that checks for the "halfway" point.

Here's the code…

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
   if (!Cookies.get('cdTime'))
   {
      var now = $.now(); // First time on page
      var timerSet = 30; // Amout of time (sec)
      var halfway = timerSet / 2;
      Cookies.set('firstTime', now,
      {
         expires: 7,
         path: '/'
      });
      Cookies.set('cdTime', timerSet,
      {
         expires: 7,
         path: '/'
      });
      var runTimer = Cookies.get('cdTime');
   }
   else
   {
      var currentTime = $.now();
      var usedTime = (currentTime - Cookies.get('firstTime')) / 1000; // Calculate and convert to sec
      var runTimer = Cookies.get('cdTime') - usedTime;
   }
   $('#cd').countdown({
      until: runTimer,
      compact: true,
      onExpiry: endCountdown,
      onTick: callBacks,
      layout: '{sn} seconds left...'
   });

   function callBacks(periods)
   {
      if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) <= halfway)
      {
         $('#cd').addClass('halfway');
      }
      else if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) === 0)
      {
         endCountdown();
      }
   }

   function endCountdown()
   {
      $('#cd').removeClass('halfway').addClass('ended');
      $('#cd').html('&#9829;');
   }
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 1em;
    font: 2em/1.4em 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica','Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
#cd {
    margin-top: 2em;
   font-family: 'Source Code Pro','Andale Mono',Monaco,'Courier New',monospace;
   font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.halfway {
    color: #0000ff;
}
.ended {
    color: #ff0000;
   font-size: 125% !important;
   line-height: 0;
}
header, footer
{
   width:66%;
   font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
footer
{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   margin-bottom: 1.5em;
   font-style: italic;
   color:  #ffa500;
}
.highlight
{
   background: #FFFBCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<header>This countdown timer uses <a href="http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html">jQuery Countdown</a>, by Keith Wood, and <a href="https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie">JavaScript Cookie</a> to work &#8212; it will continue itsa countdown regardless of browser reloads or reboots (really, try it!). <span class="highlight">Oh, and it works on mobile too</span>.</header>
<div id="cd"></div>
<footer>(Clear the “firstTime” and “cdTime" Cookies and then reload the page to start the timer over.)</footer>
```

A working example can be found here:

> http://codepen.io/ProfessorSamoff/pen/xqXrgx

Watch it through once without reloading the page and then follow the onscreen instructions in order to start the timer again and play around with reloading.

Any ideas about why this might be happening?

Thank you!

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100%, but I think `halfway` is undefined. It only gets sets when the page is loaded for the first time.

Instead of `if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) <= halfway)` try just `if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) <= halftime)`

At the top, instead of `var timerSet = 30;` before the first if statement put `totalTime = 30;` and also `halftime = Math.floor(totalTime / 2)`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite it (unless I'm misinterpreting what you're saying)… After trying your suggestion, the functionality is the same, although after the timer is complete, I can reload and get the "halfway" styled text — but the timer is already at 0-seconds.

Comment: Interesting. Try adding a breakpoint while the code is running, or console log out what is happening. Not sure what's going on, especially since it seems to be working but has odd behavior. I might look at it more closely in a sec - I'll post an update or comment if I get around to it.

Comment: No. I see what it is! (And I should have just typed the code rather than copying/pasting yours). ;) Your statement divides totalTime by 20. Hehe. So, actually, your suggestion does work, although I need to figure out how to ignore it after the timer runs out — a completely new "bug" turned up, although I think I can figure it out.

Comment: New working version here: http://codepen.io/ProfessorSamoff/pen/xqXrgx 

Thank you!

Comment: Haha nice! That's what I get for trying to do multiple things at once. Glad you got it working!